# SQL Server : how to count a column that if exist duplicate data, it reuse duplicate data first exist count number

Tags: sql

Table A

| shop | amount | count | sameShopCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shop5 | 100 | 1 | 1 |
| shop2 | 99 | 2 | 1 |
| shop3 | 98 | 3 | 1 |
| shop4 | 97 | 4 | 1 |
| shop1 | 96 | 5 | 1 |
| shop2 | 95 | 6 | 2 |
| shop4 | 94 | 7 | 2 |
| shop5 | 93 | 8 | 2 |
| shop5 | 92 | 9 | 3 |
| shop1 | 91 | 10 | 2 |
| shop5 | 90 | 11 | 4 |
| shop3 | 89 | 12 | 2 |

Expected Result (order by amount desc):

| shop | amount | expected result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| shop5 | 100 | 1 |
| shop2 | 99 | 2 |
| shop3 | 98 | 3 |
| shop4 | 97 | 4 |
| shop1 | 96 | 5 |
| shop2 | 95 | 2 |
| shop4 | 94 | 4 |
| shop5 | 93 | 1 |
| shop5 | 92 | 1 |
| shop1 | 91 | 5 |
| shop5 | 90 | 1 |
| shop3 | 89 | 3 |

I want to count `shop` column similar to `count` column in Table A. But also if shop exist more than 1 time it will reuse the first exist count number.

How can I achieved this with/without a temp table in SQL Server respectively? (SQL Server 2014 - build v12.0.6108.1)

I had tried something like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY amount DESC)

DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY shop ORDER BY amount DESC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using max and dense_rank window functions as the following:

```
with max_shop_amount as
(
  select *,
    max(amount) over (partition by shop) as mx
  from table_name 
)
select shop, amount,
    dense_rank() over (order by mx desc) expected 
from max_shop_amount
order by amount desc
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gqsWV-0_)